# Tuple initialization from IO data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, io, tuples

I would like to know what is the best way to get a tuple from data read from the input in Haskell. I often encounter this problem in competitive programming when the input is made up of several lines that contain space-separated integers. [Here is an example](https://open.kattis.com/problems/ornaments):

```
1 3 10
2 5 8
10 11 0
0 0 0
```

To read lines of integers, I use the following function:

```hs
readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = fmap (map read . words) getLine
```

Then, I transform these lists into tuples with of the appropriate size:

```hs
readInts :: IO (Int, Int, Int, Int)
readInts = fmap ((\l -> (l !! 0, l !! 1, l !! 2, l !! 3)) . map read . words) getLine
```

This approach does not seem very idiomatic to me.

The following syntax is more readable <s>but it only works for 2-tuples</s>:

```hs
readInts :: IO (Int, Int)
readInts = fmap ((\[x, y] -> (x, y)) . map read . words) getLine
```

(EDIT: as noted in the comments, the solution above works for n-tuples in general).

Is there an idiomatic way to initialize tuples from lists of integers without having to use `!!` in Haskell? Alternatively, is there a different approach to processing this type of input?

Comment: What makes you think that `(\[x, y] -> (x, y))` would only work with 2-tuples? In fact it works just fine with higher arity. — Anyways though: if you find yourself doing anything with >3 -tuples, it usually means you shouldn't be using a tuple at all but a suitable record type.

Comment: Sorry, I just double-checked in my IDE. The parsing error I had with this syntax is gone. I had probably forgotten a parenthesis and it misled me. I will edit my post.

Comment: Ultimately the most idiomatic approach is to use a real parser. With a bit of practice, Haskell parsers are very quick and easy to write. The only challenge is whether the online judge provides the necessary libraries.

Comment: @Carl What do you mean by "to use a real parser"? Something similar to the answer from _luqui_ below?

Comment: No, I mean something like the parsec family (probably megaparsec these days). I've also used Earley at times, but programming competitions often have input formats that are easiest to parse with a context-sensitive parser, which means that Earley won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
readInts :: IO (<any tuple you like>)
readInts = read . ("(" ++) . (++ ")") . intercalate "," . words <$> getLine
```

Comment: Please don't present such an unsafe solution without some warning or better alternative.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I’m not sure I agree with you — as you note, this solution certainly is very unsafe, but in the specific case of the OP’s question (competitive programming with known input format) I think this solution would be fine.

Comment: @bradrn yes, that's why I don't say it's a bad answer. But it's still a _potentially harmful_ one – people might read it without thinking about the competitive-programming context.

Comment: I knew someone would object because there's something about it's aesthetics which is very... unhaskell-like. But it's just as (un)safe as the OP's examples, and the question wasn't about safety.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the context is 'competitive programming' (something I'm only dimly aware of as a concept), I'm not sure that the following offers a particularly competitive alternative, but IMHO I'd consider it idiomatic to use one of several available parser combinators.

The `base` package comes with a module called `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`. Here's how you could use it to parse the input file from the linked article:

```
module Q57693986 where

import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

parseNumber :: ReadP Integer
parseNumber = read <$> munch1 (`elem` ['0'..'9'])

parseTriple :: ReadP (Integer, Integer, Integer)
parseTriple =
  (,,) <$> parseNumber <*> (char ' ' *> parseNumber) <*> (char ' ' *> parseNumber)

parseLine :: ReadS (Integer, Integer, Integer)
parseLine = readP_to_S (parseTriple <* eof)

parseInput :: String -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
parseInput = concatMap (fmap fst . filter (null . snd)) . fmap parseLine . lines
```

You can use the `parseInput` against this input file:

```
1 3 10
2 5 8
10 11 0
0 0 0
```

Here's a GHCi session that parses that file:

```
*Q57693986> parseInput <$> readFile "57693986.txt"
[(1,3,10),(2,5,8),(10,11,0),(0,0,0)]
```

Each `parseLine` function produces a list of tuples that match the parser; e.g.:

```
*Q57693986> parseLine "11 32 923"
[((11,32,923),"")]
```

The second element of the tuple is any remaining `String` still waiting to be parsed. In the above example, `parseLine` has completely consumed the line, which is what I'd expect for well-formed input, so the remaining `String` is empty.

The parser returns a list of alternatives if there's more than one way the input could be consumed by the parser, but again, in the above example, there's only one suggested alternative, as the line has been fully consumed.

The `parseInput` function throws away any tuple that hasn't been fully consumed, and then picks only the first element of any remaining tuples.

This approach has often served me with puzzles such as [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com), where the input files tend to be well-formed.

Comment: Your `parseNumber` is unnecessary unsafe. You should use `readPrec` to parse a number. You can either lift everything into `ReadPrec` or lower the number parsing to `ReadP`. Of course, something like attoparsec or megaparsec is probably a better choice than anything in base.

Comment: @dfeuer Thank you; I didn't know that, but I'll try that next time it comes up for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to generate a parser that works generically for any tuple (of reasonable size). It requires the library [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass, 
             FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies, TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Generics.SOP
import Generics.SOP (hsequence, hcpure,Proxy,to,SOP(SOP),NS(Z),IsProductType,All)
import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec
import Text.Read

componentP :: Read a => ReadP a
componentP = munch isSpace *> readPrec_to_P readPrec 1

productP :: (IsProductType a xs, All Read xs) => ReadP a
productP = 
    let parserOutside = hsequence (hcpure (Proxy @Read) componentP)
     in Generics.SOP.to . SOP . Z <$> parserOutside
```

For example:

```
*Main> productP @(Int,Int,Int) `readP_to_S` " 1 2 3 "
[((1,2,3)," ")]
```

It allows components of different types, as long as they all have a `Read` instance.

It also parses records that have a `Generics.SOP.Generic` instance:

```
data Stuff = Stuff { x :: Int, y :: Bool } 
             deriving (Show,GHC.Generics.Generic,Generics.SOP.Generic)
```

For example:

```
*Main> productP @Stuff `readP_to_S` " 1 True"
[(Stuff {x = 1, y = True},"")]
```